# How to return a json object from a function in jquery with no ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, callback

So I am trying to make a web application, in which I need to show the details of the cart on the confirmation dialog() but I am not able to store the variable since it is asynchronous function calls. So I tried using function callbacks, but no break thru. 
Please help how to get the data into cart_items from the function getValueUsingClass() .

Created a deferred object but I don't how to use it. Help required so badly. I am so frustrated about this. So please help, thanks in advance

```js
//this is client.js


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var cart_items = [
      //this is the variable that needs to be stored with the cart items which will be coming from getValueUsingClass() function.
        ];


        //collecting the items into a json object to send to the server 
        $(".checkboxlist").click(function () {
            cart_items = (getValueUsingClass());
            console.log(cart_items);
        })


    //function to store the values in cart_items but not able to store
        function getValueUsingClass(setValue) {
            /* declare a checkbox array */
            var chkArray = [];
            /* look for all checkboxes that have a class 'check' attached to it and check if it was checked */
            $(".checkboxlist:checked").each(function () {
                var element = this;
                var cart_item = {
                    id: this.id,
                    item: this.name,
                    cost: Number(this.value),
                    quantity: 1
                }
                chkArray.push(cart_item);
                setValue(cart_items);//tried to use this as a callback function
            })

            /* we join the array separated by the comma */
            function setValue(cart_items) {
                cart_items = chkArray;
                console.log("hell" + cart_items[0].id);
            }

            /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */

plate is the cart for this, I am using local variable chkArray to store the print the data on the cart

            $(".plate").on('click', function () {
                $('.plate_items').html(" ");
                console.log(cart_items[0].id);
                for (itemIterator = 0; itemIterator < chkArray.length; itemIterator++) {
                    $('.plate_items').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + chkArray[itemIterator].cost + '</li>');
                }
            });

            return chkArray;
        }

        $('.proceed_btn').on('click', function () {
            console.log("hello");
            console.log(cart_items);
            let details = [{
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                empid: $('#empid').val()
            }]
            console.log(details[0].name + details[0].email + details[0].empid);
            cart_items = cart_items.concat(details);


        })
    })
```

```html
//this is index.html
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid header">
            <span class="main_title" style="float:left">Eatachi</span>
            <nav class="nav navigation">
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg plate" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Plate</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="empid">Employee ID:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empid">
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Cart Details</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body plate_items">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                            <ul class="list-group">

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success proceed_btn">Proceed to payment</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <header>
                            <h3>Veg Alacarte</h3>
                        </header>
                        <article class="well well-lg">


                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="collapseListGroupHeading1">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseListGroup1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseListGroup1">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail news-pic center-block" src="imgs/1.jpg" />
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseListGroup1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseListGroupHeading1">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="14" type="checkbox" value="50"> Veg Fried Rice Rs.50</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="15" type="checkbox" value="60"> Veg Biryani Rs.60</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="16" type="checkbox" value="70"> Paneer Fried Rice Rs.70</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="17" type="checkbox" value="50"> Veg Noodles Rs.50</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="18" type="checkbox" value="35"> Curd Rice Rs.35</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="19" type="checkbox" value="35"> Sambar Rice Rs.35</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="20" type="checkbox" value="35"> Veg Pulao Rs.35</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="21" type="checkbox" value="35"> Lemon Rice Rs.35</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="22" type="checkbox" value="15"> Veg Curry Rs.15</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="23" type="checkbox" value="10"> Curd Rs.10</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="24" type="checkbox" value="10"> Dal Rs.10</li>

                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">

                            </ul>
                        </article>

                    </div>

                    <div class=" col-lg-4">
                        <header>
                            <h3>Diet</h3>
                        </header>
                        <article class="well well-lg">


                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="collapseListGroupHeading1">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#dietList" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseListGroup1">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail news-pic center-block" src="imgs/2.jpg" />
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="dietList" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseListGroupHeading1">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="25" type="checkbox" value="50"> North Diet Rs.50</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="26" type="checkbox" value="50"> South Diet Rs.50</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxlist" id="27" type="checkbox" value="70"> South Diet Royal Rs.70</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">

                            </ul>
                        </article>


                    </div>

                    <div class=" col-lg-4">
                        <header>
                            <h3>Non Veg Alacarte</h3>
                        </header>
                        <article class="well well-lg">


                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="collapseListGroupHeading1">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nonVegList" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseListGroup1">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail news-pic center-block" src="imgs/3.jpg" />
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="nonVegList" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseListGroupHeading1">
                                <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="1" type="checkbox" value="130"> Chicken Biryani Rs.130</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="2" type="checkbox" value="130"> Fish Biryani- Rs.130</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="3" type="checkbox" value="130"> Prawn65 Biryani Rs.130</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="4" type="checkbox" value="100"> Chicken Dum Biryani Rs.100</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="5" type="checkbox" value="110"> Chicken Roast Biryani Rs.110</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="6" type="checkbox" value="120"> Chicken Boneless Biryani Rs.120</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="7" type="checkbox" value="70"> Egg Biryani Rs.70</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="8" type="checkbox" value="60"> Egg Curry with Roti Rs.60</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="9" type="checkbox" value="80"> Egg Curry with Paratha Rs.80</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="10" type="checkbox" value="70"> Chicken Fried Rice Rs.70</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="11" type="checkbox" value="70"> Chicken Noodles Rs.70</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="12" type="checkbox" value="60"> Egg Fried Rice Rs.60</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                        <input class="checkboxlist" id="13" type="checkbox" value="60"> Egg Noodles Rs.60</li>



                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group">

                            </ul>
                        </article>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="footer">

            <div class="copyright">
                <span id="copyright-year">©2018</span>

            </div>

        </div>


    </body>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/client.js"></script>


    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Nothing about your code is asynchronous. Why do you believe you need to use Deferred objects at all?

Comment: Because the cart_items is not being populated

Comment: If it is not asynchronous why is not the variable not having any details even after the value is being returned

Comment: You never put any data in to `cart_items`, aside from the `details` object in the `proceed_btn` click handler. It would really help to see a working example of this, as your code seems rather disjointed

Answer (score 0):

Async call in javascript doesn't return you an answer immediately but it returns you a promise that eventually it will give you the answer you'd expect. Usually, promises have a `then` method which is a callback function which the promise exposes to access the data when it is ready. So, the point is that you can make use of your data in this `then` method. For more detailed reference go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Promises can be used other than URL calls?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is not with any function callbacks or asynchronous, the values I am setting to cart_items should be passed using push() method instead of assigning it directly.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var cart_items = [
      //this is the variable that needs to be stored with the cart items which will be coming from getValueUsingClass() function.
        ];


        //collecting the items into a json object to send to the server 
        $(".checkboxlist").click(function () {
            cart_items = (getValueUsingClass());
            console.log(cart_items);
        })


    //function to store the values in cart_items but not able to store
        function getValueUsingClass(setValue) {
            /* declare a checkbox array */
            var chkArray = [];
            /* look for all checkboxes that have a class 'check' attached to it and check if it was checked */
            $(".checkboxlist:checked").each(function () {
                var element = this;
                var cart_item = {
                    id: this.id,
                    item: this.name,
                    cost: Number(this.value),
                    quantity: 1
                }
                chkArray.push(cart_item);
                setValue(cart_items);//tried to use this as a callback function
            })

            /* we join the array separated by the comma */
            function setValue(cart_items) {
                //cart_items = chkArray; this is the mistake
                 cart_items.push(chkArray);//this is the correct way because I am passing the reference but the following array will not accept the reference as a value.
                console.log("hell" + cart_items[0].id);
            }

            /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */

plate is the cart for this, I am using local variable chkArray to store the print the data on the cart

            $(".plate").on('click', function () {
                $('.plate_items').html(" ");
                console.log(cart_items[0].id);
                for (itemIterator = 0; itemIterator < chkArray.length; itemIterator++) {
                    $('.plate_items').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + chkArray[itemIterator].cost + '</li>');
                }
            });

            return chkArray;
        }

        $('.proceed_btn').on('click', function () {
            console.log("hello");
            console.log(cart_items);
            let details = [{
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                empid: $('#empid').val()
            }]
            console.log(details[0].name + details[0].email + details[0].empid);
            cart_items = cart_items.concat(details);


        })
    })
```